# KeyMap on a flat Dataset (i.e. Dataset@Association)

Tags: bugs, dataset, associations

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.1**

*See Kuba's anwser below for the bug*.

*`Dataset` is new in 10.0.0.*

---

How can I go from

```
Dataset[<|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2, "C" -> 3|>]
```

[image]

to

```
Dataset[KeyMap[f, <|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2, "C" -> 3|>]]
```

[image]

(which for some reason is not formatting),  without converting the original Dataset using Normal?

---

**Edit**

Kuba: tag [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) added since WRI confirmed that solution from my answer reveals one.

Comment: Was fixed in 10.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just starting with those associations stuff but this seems to work:

```
 Dataset[<|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2, "C" -> 3|>][ KeyMap[f, #] & ]
```

while I'm not entirely sure why this does not

```
Dataset[<|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2, "C" -> 3|>][ KeyMap[f] ]
```

---

p.s. note about formatting. it is not done because `f["A"]` is not a string and "proper" associacion key should be a string (for querying purposes).

Comment: It seems like a bug to me. Those should both work.

Comment: @StefanR I was going to report that but then I saw your profile. :) Or should I do this anyway?

Comment: I've already notified the developers of this issue :)

Answer (score 1):

If the function f is undefined the result is not formatted, but if you have a defined the function it works fine:

```
ds = Dataset[<|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2, "C" -> 3|>]
```

so

```
Dataset@KeyMap[f][<|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2, "C" -> 3|>]
```

does not format the output, but with `g[x_String] := x ~~ "1"` one gets formatted output

```
Dataset@KeyMap[g][<|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2, "C" -> 3|>]
```